# What are the missing members in this sequence based on the digits 0 to 9?

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

Find the missing members?

0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, ?, ?, ?

Hint 1

> No arithmetic operations involved in developing the series. Lateral thinking needed.

Comment: Hint..This series is not based on any mathematical operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> $1,1,0$, and the sequence is, in a '[normal font](https://designshack.net/articles/inspiration/number-fonts-10-stylish-examples/)', the number of straight lines, reading backwards. So $9$ is all curves, so is $8$, $7$ is two straight lines, $6$=0 $5$=2, $4$=3, $3$=0, $2$=1, $1$=1. $0$=0.

Comment: Got it JMP!!!...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple answer which I believe works nonetheless.

> 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, **2**, **3**, **4**, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, ...

because

> zeroes occur after skipping zero, one, two and so on terms and clearly the sequence starts at two.

Comment: Not right.........

Comment: Also... sequence only has ten numbers corresponding to zero to nine digits.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

> 0, 0, and 5, respectively.

Explanation:

> I looked this sequence up on the OEIS and found that [A095759](https://oeis.org/A095759) would look sensible for this challenge.

Comment: No..you would not find any of my sequences in oeis usually.